# Count comma seperated values in mysql ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, count, order-by

I have a table name products:

```
id      -    pro_name   -            ip               -     date_created
 1      -    abc1       - 27.106.121.23,27.106.121.86 -     2018-08-15 13:32:00
 2      -    abc2       - 27.106.121.26               -     2018-08-16 13:32:00
 3      -    abc3       -                             -     2018-08-17 13:32:00
 4      -    abc4       - 27.106.121.23,27.106.121.86 -     2018-08-18 13:32:00
```

Now i want to display data as number of views, i want to count numbers of ip as views and sort table as maximum views.

Currently i am using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY COUNT(ip) DESC,date_created DESC
```

I want data as:

```
id      -    pro_name   -            ip               -     date_created
 4      -    abc4       - 27.106.121.23,27.106.121.86 -     2018-08-18 13:32:00
 1      -    abc1       - 27.106.121.23,27.106.121.86 -     2018-08-15 13:32:00
 2      -    abc2       - 27.106.121.26               -     2018-08-16 13:32:00
 3      -    abc3       -                             -     2018-08-17 13:32:00
```

Comment: `ORDER BY LENGTH(ip) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ip, ',', '')) DESC, date_created DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Or if it was a sane table structure (avoid lists in columns) with IPs its own tables as ip(product_id, ip):

```
SELECT id, pro_name, group_concat(ip), date_created, COUNT(*) as c  
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN ip ON products.id = ip.product_id 
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY c DESC, date_created DESC
```

Comment: thanks.. i got your answer but Akina solved my problem.

Comment: Good to know. Keep this answer in mind for when the length of the IP list exceeds the width of a column or every query regarding IPs becomes hard.